# Jasmine JS: How to write unit tests for Cordova SQLite plugin queries?

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova, jasmine, cordova-plugins

Let's suppose, we have an `angular` service that has a function as follows:

```
this.getAllBranches = function () {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("select * from branch", [], function (tx, res) {
            var branchList = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                var branch = {};
                branch.id = res.rows.item(i).id;
                branch.code = res.rows.item(i).code;
                branch.address = res.rows.item(i).address;
                branch.city = res.rows.item(i).city;
                branch.state = res.rows.item(i).state;
                branch.zip = res.rows.item(i).zip;

                branchList.push(branch);
            }

            deferred.resolve(branchList);
        }, function (t, e) {
            alert('An error occurred getting list of branches.');
            deferred.reject(e);
        });
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

How do we test the above function?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [cordova-plugin-test-framework](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-test-framework) - all core cordova plugins use it for auto and manual testing; the workflow is the following:

- Create a new application,
- Add three plugins:

  `cordova plugin add path-to-cloned-plugin`
  `cordova plugin add path-to-cloned-plugin/tests`
  `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-test-framework.git`
- Update config.xml at the root of your app - change `<content src="index.html">` to `<content src="cdvtests/index.html">`,
- Run application.

You can investigate how it is done in [Cordova-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/blob/master-public/tests/tests.js) as a reference.
Additional sqlite tests can be found [here](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/tree/master-public/spec/www/spec).